# Remove quotes from imported JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am exporting some data with a python script that does this:

```py
data = {......., 'noTick': 'true'}
with open('items.json', 'w') as sample:
    sample.write(json.dumps(data))
```

which I am trying to import (`src/data/items.json`) in a vue app this way:

```
export default [
    {
        "PropertyOne": "ValueOne",
        .....,
        "noTick": "true"
    },

    {
        ......
    }
]
```

Then in my component.vue I import it:

```
import ALL_ITEMS from 'src/data/items.json'
...
const codes = ALL_ITEMS
```

The problem is that the `q-tree` component from quasar framework expects the `noTick` property to be unquoted:

```
{
    "PropertyOne": "ValueOne",
    .....,
    noTick: true
}
```

So far I have only come up with:

1. Doing find/replace in vscode.
2. Convert toString and back to JSON:

```js
    export default JSON.stringify(
        {
            "PropertyOne": "ValueOne",
            .....,
            "noTick": "true"
        }
    )
```

and in `Component.vue`:

```
import ALL_ITEMS from 'src/data/items.json'
...
const codes = JSON.parse(ALL_ITEMS)
```

and This fails as well. Is there any way to change this property to  one without quotes by using JavaScript?

NOTE: I have edited the question for more clarity

Comment: Is there JSON actually involved?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The items.json comes this way from a python script: `[
    {
        "PropertyOne": "ValueOne",
        .....,
        "noTick": "true"
    },

    {
        ......
    }
]`

Comment: You don’t unquote the key, you unquote the value. Provided it’s a valid primitive type, which a boolean is, it is valid JSON.

Comment: `items.json`, despite the extension, exports a JavaScript array (not to be confused with JSON, which is a text serialisation format). In JSON, an unquoted object key is invalid. In JavaScript object literals, it's 100% equivalent to a quoted key (as long as it doesn't contain special chars, in which case it's invalid too). I have the impression that this quoted/unquoted thing is a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply unquote it, JSON can represent primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans, and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).

```js
    export default [
        {
            "PropertyOne": "ValueOne",
            .....,
            "noTick": true
        },
    
        {
            ......
        }
    ]
```

**Edit:** in your python script you should do the same:

```py
data = {......., 'noTick': True}
with open('items.json', 'w') as sample:
     sample.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Hello. You have really helped me with your answer. Please edit it to reflect the changes I have made to the question, and I can accept it

Comment: @VictorMHerasmePerez Why edit it tho, the answer is still valid?

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the python script to export: `"noTick": True`, so basically unticking and changing to a boolean instead of string solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

if you are importing .json file there is no need for ***export default***

you can just remove it and use as simple .json with {} only

or you can rename file as .js (simple javascript file), leaving export default

ex:

```
export default {
    name: 'John Doe',
}
```